# Making code more efficient and less a copy and paste

Tags: php, mysql

I've been working on a piece of code that that pulls the name of a guild and with it the information of boss/monsters said guild has killed in an online game. There are many many monsters in this game and every one has three difficulty settings. I have managed to get the code to do what i want however it has an enormous amount of copy and paste and ive only done about 1/5 of the total amount of enteries. I really cant think how to make this code less of a giant bloat. This is the code for just one monster for the 3 difficulty settings as you can see it's alot just for one. there are probably another 60 of these!. Can anybody help me understand better ways to do this. Thanks!

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM `phpbb_profile_fields_data`';

  $result = $db->sql_query($sql);

  while ($row = $db->sql_fetchrow($result))
  {      
    /////////////////////////////////// START - 8 MAN BONETHRASHER
    $normal = '';
    $hard = '';
    $nightmare = '';
    /////// START - CHECK NORMAL
    if ($row['pf_kp_em_no_bonethr'] == '1')
        {
            $normal = '&nbsp;<img src="/styles/subsilver2/theme/images/soap/no.png" />';
        }       
    else if ($row['pf_kp_em_no_bonethr'] == '2')
        {
            $normal = '';
        }       
    else if (is_null($row['pf_kp_em_no_bonethr'])) 
        {
            echo "Boss was set as NULL This should not happen!";
        }
    else
        {
            echo "Sosia messed up go hit him in the face.";
        }
    /////// END - CHECK NORMAL  
    /////// START - CHECK HARD
    if ($row['pf_kp_em_ha_bonethr'] == '1')
        {
            $hard = '&nbsp;<img src="/styles/subsilver2/theme/images/soap/ha.png" />';
        }       
    else if ($row['pf_kp_em_ha_bonethr'] == '2')
        {
            $hard = '';
        }       
    else if (is_null($row['pf_kp_em_ha_bonethr'])) 
        {
            echo "Boss was set as NULL This should not happen!";
        }
    else
        {
            echo "Sosia messed up go hit him in the face.";
        }
    /////// END - CHECK HARD    
    /////// START - CHECK NIGHTMARE
    if ($row['pf_kp_em_kn_bonethr'] == '1')
        {
            $nightmare ='&nbsp;<img src="/styles/subsilver2/theme/images/soap/kn.png" />';
        }       
    else if ($row['pf_kp_em_kn_bonethr'] == '2')
        {
            $nightmare = '';
        }       
    else if (is_null($row['pf_kp_em_kn_bonethr'])) 
        {
            echo "Boss was set as NULL This should not happen!";
        }
    else
        {
            echo "Sosia messed up go hit him in the face.";
        }
    /////// END - CHECK NIGHTMARE   

if ($normal == '' && $hard == '' && $nightmare == '') 
        {

        }
    else
        {
            $template->assign_block_vars('8m_bonethrasher', array(
            'VAR1' => $row['pf_guild_name'],
            'VAR2' => $normal,
            'VAR3' => $hard,
            'VAR4' => $nightmare,
            ));
        }

  }

  $db->sql_freeresult($result);
```

Comment: Not 100% sure what your asking, but look into `include()`

Comment: Well I would basically have to create another 60 of those blocks of code and all I would be changing is the row filed "pf_kp_em_no_bonethr" to a different boss so I was wondering if there would be a way that I could recycle code that would stop me having to copy that block out 60 times

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm still slightly fuzzy at what you are trying to do, but I'll give helping you out a shot.

You could probably get away will creating a class that does all of this.

For example:

```
class checks {

    public function checkBosses($normalBoss, $hardBoss, $nightmareBoss) {

        $difficulties = array();

        $difficulties['normal'] = array('boss' => $normalBoss);
        $difficulties['hard'] = array('boss' => $hardBoss);
        $difficulties['nightmare'] = array('boss' => $nightmareBoss);

        foreach ($this->difficulties as $difficulty -> $boss) {
            $this->difficulties[$difficulty]['result'] = checkDifficulty($boss['boss'], $difficulty);
        }

        $normal = $this->difficulties['normal']['result'];
        $hard = $this->difficulties['hard']['result'];
        $nightmare = $this->difficulties['nightmare']['result'];


        if ($normal == '' && $hard == '' && $nightmare == '') {
            return null;
        } else {
            return array(
                'normal' => $normal,
                'hard' => $hard,
                'nightmare' => $nightmare,
            );
        }
    }

    protected function checkDifficulty($boss, $difficulty) {

        if ($difficulty == 'normal') {
            $image = '&nbsp;<img src="/styles/subsilver2/theme/images/soap/no.png" />';
        } else if ($difficulty == 'hard') {
            $image = '&nbsp;<img src="/styles/subsilver2/theme/images/soap/ha.png" />';
        } else if ($difficulty == 'nightmare') {
            $image = '&nbsp;<img src="/styles/subsilver2/theme/images/soap/kn.png" />';
        } 

        if ($boss == '1') {
            return $image;
        } else if ($boss == '2') {
            return '';
        } else if (is_null($boss)) {
            echo "Boss was set as NULL This should not happen!";
        } else {
            echo "Sosia messed up go hit him in the face.";
        }
    }
}
```

Then all you would need to do is call:

```
$checkResult = checks::checkBosses($row['pf_kp_em_no_bonethr'], $row['pf_kp_em_ha_bonethr'], $row['pf_kp_em_kn_bonethr']);

if ($checkResult != null) {
    $template->assign_block_vars('8m_bonethrasher', array(
        'VAR1' => $row['pf_guild_name'],
        'VAR2' => $normal,
        'VAR3' => $hard,
        'VAR4' => $nightmare,
    ));
}
```

Comment: I would suggest to take all those if/else and make some methods out of it...for code reuse

Comment: @Mike For some reason this single line is causing an internal server error and I don't know why. I put this class outside of the while loop and the $checkresult within it

`$checkResult = checks::checkBosses($row['pf_kp_em_no_bonethr'], $row['pf_kp_em_ha_bonethr'], $row['pf_kp_em_kn_bonethr']);`

Comment: You could also try initializing the class with: $checker = new check(); and then calling $checkResult = $checker-> checkBosses($row[' pf_kp_em_no_bonethr'], $row['pf_k p_em_ha_bonethr'], $row['pf_kp_em _kn_bonethr']);

Comment: @Mike still no dice. I have the full page here if it's any help [link]http://ryanw.co.uk/page.txt

Answer (score 0):

If you can retrieve an array of bosses, you can do a foreach loop on them to run that same bit of code for each boss like this:

```
foreach ($bosses as $boss) {
    //Full code to be repeated for each boss here
}
```